# How can I write this jquery on() the correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-on

Here is what I have

```
$('.test').on({
    'click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        if( $(this).hasClass('selector') ) {
        }
        if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ) {
        }
        if( $(this).hasClass('next') ) {
        }
        return false;
    },
    mouseenter: function(){
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
    }
});
```

I know this is the wrong syntax, so what is the right syntax? I know I can write it if I separated the click and mouse events. But is there a way to combine them or do I need to separate them? Thanks for your time

Comment: You can find a description and examples in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/. You probably want `.on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )`.

Comment: I didn't see an example with what I wanted so that's why I wrote the combination what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make 2 separate calls if you don't wish to use the same selector in both:

```
$('.test').on({
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {} //null selector/no selector here so these events only fire on `.test` itself
}).on("click", "a", function(event) { //Selector here so this event only fires for `a` descendants of `.test`
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('selector')) {}
    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {}
    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {}
    return false;
});
```

You also forgot to specify the event parameter, which would have caused a bug in IE and firefox

Comment: yes the event parameter, thanks 
Does the selector at the end apply to all 3 events or just click? I need the click only on a

Comment: +1 for giving solution using OP code, I wish I could give you more... I tested it over here http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/BPZdS/

Comment: @Huangism ok I have now changed that

Comment: yea that's what I have now chaining it. Although pointy is correct as well, I will give you chek mark for the after-effort

Answer (score 4):

You can chain the calls:

```
$('.test').on('click', 'a', function() { ... })
 .on('mouseenter', 'a', function() { ... })
 .on('mouseleave', 'a', function() { ... });
```

I guess if you wanted to you could have one handler that checked the event type, but this seems less weird.

Comment: thanks I give it to another answer for his after-effort but chaining it is the right way to go

Answer (score 2):

`.on()` also accepts a *map*:

```
$('.test').on({
    click: function() {
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    }
}, 'a');
```

Comment: I needed the a from the test div

Comment: @Huangism: thats basically what this statement is saying. Handler each `click`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event from every *anchor* which is a child from `.test`.

Comment: Yes but if it's being used like `.delegate()` can you do this?  (Obviously I'm off to check the docs ... :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Obama would say, "yes you can!"

Comment: Oh I see, durr; but you can't have a map with a distinct "filter" selector per event type (which in this case isn't necessary). That's nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the hover events on the wrapper element, then you need to bind its events separately, as it is a separate element.

```
$('.test').on({
    click: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('selector')) {}
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {}
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {}
        return false;
    }
}, "a");

$('.test').hover( function(event){
        // This in the mouse enter handler  
    },
    function(event){
        // This is the mouse leave handler
    }
);
```